# How to input dataset while using Salesforce-merlion package for timeseries forecasting

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, salesforce-merlion

I have installed Salesforce-Merlion package in my conda-environment. Now I want to use my own dataset to run the algorithm for forecasting. Here I need only one univariate series to forecast. But I cannot figure out how to do that. As there are some variables which I cannot find how to initialize those. In the example provided in GIThub, using some already splitted dataset. Can someone can help me out here?

GIThub example for forecasting is like this:

```
from merlion.utils import TimeSeries from ts_datasets.forecast import M4
# Data loader returns pandas DataFrames, which we convert to Merlion TimeSeries
time_series, metadata = M4(subset="Hourly")[0]
train_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[metadata.trainval])
test_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[~metadata.trainval])
```

The complete code with internal dataset is available in the following link:
https://github.com/salesforce/Merlion/tree/main/examples/forecast
(Here they are using their internal dataset `M4`)

Now, I have to use my dataset. So my code is like this:

```
from merlion.utils import TimeSeries

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Doyel_De_Sarkar\Desktop\forecasting\15786_GIK.csv')
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df.sort_values('ts', inplace=True)
trainval = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i <= (round((len(df)*0.75),0)):
        trainval.append(True)
    else:
        trainval.append(False)
 df['trainval'] = trainval

 df = df.drop(columns=['wday', 'hour'])

 from merlion.utils import UnivariateTimeSeries

 kpi = UnivariateTimeSeries(
     time_stamps=df.ts,      # timestamps in units of seconds
     values=df.saps_total,        # time series values
     name="kpi"       # optional: a name for this univariate
 )

 kpi_label = UnivariateTimeSeries(
     time_stamps=df.ts,  # timestamps in units of seconds
     values=df.trainval         # time series values
 )
 from merlion.utils import TimeSeries
 time_series, metadata = kpi, kpi_label
 
 train_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[metadata.trainval])
 test_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[~metadata.trainval])
 test_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[~metadata.trainval])
```

I am getting this following error

```
'UnivariateTimeSeries' object has no attribute 'trainval'
```

at this line:

```
train_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[metadata.trainval])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you SalmonKiller for taking out time to look into the issue. The dataset used in the github has a very weird data structure, hence I had to create the column trainval and set the metadata as the column df[['trainval']]. The univariate I had created was of no use. The issue was there with indexing. After I set the time stamp column as index , the issue got solved.

Here is the code which is running fine now.

```
   import os
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   from merlion.models.forecast.smoother import MSESConfig, MSES
   from merlion.transform.resample import TemporalResample
   from merlion.utils import TimeSeries

   df = pd.read_csv(r'<file.csv>')

  df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
  df.set_index('ts', inplace=True)
  df.sort_values('ts', inplace=True)
  hours = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='H')

  mean = df.saps_total.mean()
  df = df.reindex(hours, fill_value=mean)

  trainval = []
  for i in range(len(df)):
      if i <= (round((len(df)*0.75),0)):
         trainval.append(True)
      else:
         trainval.append(False)
  df['trainval'] = trainval

  df = df.drop(columns=['wday', 'hour'])

  from merlion.utils import TimeSeries
  time_series = df[['saps_total']]
  metadata = df[['trainval']]
  train_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[metadata.trainval])
  test_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[~metadata.trainval])

  from merlion.models.forecast.arima import Arima, ArimaConfig
  config1 = ArimaConfig(max_forecast_steps=len(time_series[~metadata.trainval].index), order=(0, 1, 0),
                  
  transform=TemporalResample(granularity="1h"))
  model1  = Arima(config1)
  model1.train(train_data=train_data)
  test_pred, test_err = model1.forecast(time_stamps=test_data.time_stamps)
  print(test_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because `trainval` is not a parameter of the `TimeSeries` class. In the example from GitHub that you shared, `metadata` is a pandas timeframe, but you're constructing a `TimeSeries` object out of `kpi_label`.

I'm not sure exactly what your dataset looks like, but try using:

```
kpi_labels = df.trainval
```

instead.